# Are bots used for spam filtering in SE.AI currently?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In stack overflow there is a couple community bots that aims to help moderation by automatically flagging posts with the stack exchange API, like [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/17/meet-the-bots-that-help-moderate-stack-overflow/). Is bots like this used in artificial intelligence stack exchange currently?

If one decided to create a bot for accelerating moderation by flagging duplicates and off-topic questions, is that specifically allowed in the website? A bot that helps to automatically flag questions and duplicates may help a lot in removing and noticing unwanted posts and answers, and with a machine learning algorithm one can classify it to a very high degree of accuracy.

Related questions:

[Would more-heavily involved moderation bots be beneficial to Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299383/544012)

[Present and future of bots on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261172/544012)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey) is active on Artificial Intelligence as well, and it's [automatically flagging posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/295232) of which it's 99.75% sure it's spam. Fortunately, Artificial Intelligence [doesn't see as much spam as the rest of the network](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/sites/dash?utf8=%E2%9C%93&site_id=322&months=12&tab=all), and only 117 flags have been cast last year. Most (all?) other bots in that blog post are tuned towards Stack Overflow content and can't be ported directly to Artificial Intelligence, though some of them might be after some adjustments.

> If one decided to create a bot for accelerating moderation by flagging duplicates and off-topic questions, is that specifically allowed in the website? A bot that helps to automatically flag questions and duplicates may help a lot in removing and noticing unwanted posts and answers

Yes, that is allowed, as long as you don't do anything stupid. You need to be reasonably sure the flag accuracy is at least as high as the average human user (which is about 95% IIRC). If you get flag banned because of a bad algorithm, that's your own problem.

> and with a machine learning algorithm one can classify it to a very high degree of accuracy.

Well ... that might surprise you. SmokeDetector relies heavily on old-school regexes. We've tried a few times to classify spam based on machine learning, and we got nowhere near the 95% mark, let alone the 99.75% needed for autoflagging. (That percentage is so high because validated spam flags carry a heavy penalty.) Determining off-topic and duplicate questions looks even more challenging to me, but I hope you can surprise us.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe one can develop a system to simply notify a user if it detected a duplicate question, though not immediately flag it.

Comment: Btw thanks very much for your information.

Comment: You're welcome. There is a bot ([SOCVFinder](https://stackapps.com/q/6910/34061)) which provides live notifications (via chat) for duplicates on Stack Overflow. Its author is no longer on Stack Exchange; it runs under [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6294609/queen) so you might want to ping PetterFriberg in the SOBotics chatroom.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks very much for your answer. Maybe I will try to design a bot to detect replicates and spams as a fun project. Thanks very much again for your answer m